# Servlet execution threw an exception

Tags: eclipse, hibernate, jsp

I'm new to hibernate please get out of me. I'm already wast 2 days with this error. I'm writing a web application using Eclipse IDE and web server as a Tomcat

I'm getting the following Exception.

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    com.rmi.util.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:15)
    com.rmi.DAO.NewProvinceDAO.add(NewProvinceDAO.java:14)
    com.rmi.servlet.ProvinceServlet.doPost(ProvinceServlet.java:60)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:643)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)


root cause 

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/cfg/AnnotationConfiguration
    com.rmi.util.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:12)
    com.rmi.DAO.NewProvinceDAO.add(NewProvinceDAO.java:14)
    com.rmi.servlet.ProvinceServlet.doPost(ProvinceServlet.java:60)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:643)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
```

This is my Hibernate util class

```
    import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
        import org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration;

        public class HibernateUtil {
            private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;

        static{
            try{
                sessionFactory = new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
            }catch(Throwable ex){
                System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
                throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
            }
        }

        public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
            return sessionFactory;
        }
    }
```

Here I'm try into access via servlet

My hibernate util class is working fine as a java application and I can add record to the database. But as a web application I'm getting above exception.

[image]

Comment: Did you put the Hibernate jars under `WEB-INF/lib` of the Container ?

Comment: Use Ctrl+Shift+T:>AnnotationConfiguration to locate which jar contains this file, then check if it in the classpath of the web application (i.e. WEB-INF/lib)

Comment: Do I need to put all jar file into WEB-INF/lib?